# ¿Cómo decodificar las vocales acentuadas y la ñ?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, utf-8, codificación

Para generar modelos he descargado un *dataset* con artículos de **wikipedia** y los he puesto en el formato que me exigía MALLET de Java para usarlos. Al empezar a generar modelos me he dado cuenta que las *vocales acentuadas* y la *ñ*, las sistituye por el icono -> `"�"` .
Por lo que al hacer la *"limpieza"* del texto, las palabras acentuadas y/o con ñ, las desprecia.

Es decir, si tenemos la palabra `p�gina` después del proceso tendremos dos `palabras`, `p` y `gina`, las cuales carecen de significado.

Para ver la codificación del fichero en cuestión he utilizado el siguiente comando en la terminal de Ubuntu:

```
$ file -bi wiki_00

text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Y usando:

```
$ echo $LANG
es_ES.UTF-8
```

Todo el texto está guardado en un txt, ¿alguien sabría como recuperar estas letras?

Comment: La cuestión es que todo esto sucede antes de programar. Es decir, en el proceso de preparar los archivos. La cuestión es que al descargarlos, llegan así a mi pc y querría saber si habría manera de reconvertir esos "?" en la letra en cuestión.

Comment: Cuando haces esa comprobación estás usando un editor de texto (gedit, Visual Studio Code... etc). Intenta comprobar qué codificación *está asumiendo* tu editor, porque seguramente no sea la correcta.

Comment: Lo hago en la terminal utilizando la expresión less, que es donde aparecen las interrogaciones, si uso less -r , entonces aparecen <ED> para las í, <FA> para las ú...

Comment: Si pones en tu terminal `echo $LANG`, ¿qué obtienes?

Comment: Obtengo `es_ES.UTF-8`

Comment: Tu terminal está en UTF-8 y tu fichero, según parece por tu edición, está en `iso-8859-1`

Comment: ¿Y sabrías como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Ubuntu (o cualquier distro, realmente) puedes probar a transformar de un formato a otro de la siguiente manera:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 Myfile.txt -o resultado.txt
#      ^ \________/  ^ \___/ \________/  ^ \___________/
#      |     |       |   |       |       |     |
#    from    |       to  |       |       |   Fichero salida
#            |           |       |       |   
#    formato de entrada  |    fichero    |
#                        |               |   
#                 formato de salida     output
```

Los parámetros `-f ISO-8859-1` son opcionales, dejando a `iconv` la responsabilidad de averiguar el formato de origen.

Nota: El fichero de salida ha de ser distinto del de entrada o borrará anticipadamente el fichero de entrada y no funcionará

Comment: Si no utilizo -f y el formato de entrada me devuelve el error: *Exitus es un ticonv: secuencia de entrada ilegal en la posición 119*
En cambio si utilizo el comando completo me devuelve el archivo con todas las letras acentuadas las ñ etc, pero el archivo original sigue siendo el mismo. Para añadir esos cambios al archivo original, debo añadir algún parámetro más? Gracias!

Comment: Respuesta actualizada

Comment: Ahora si, gracias!!